# Coordinate Layout in Linear Layout: Component not fixed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout

As title described, the position of the android logo in rounded image view is not fixed.

App sometimes rendered correctly as what I designed like this:
[image: Layout behave correctly]

But sometimes the layout behave in this way:
[image: Layout behave incorrectly]

Below attached my layout .xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="275dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_iv_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_bg"/>

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_riv_user"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_iv_background"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        app:riv_border_color="#333333"
        app:riv_border_width="2dip"
        app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
        app:riv_oval="true"
        app:riv_tile_mode="clamp" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/profile_tv_full_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/profile_rv_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: works perfectly well in my emulator!

Comment: on which Android version are you testing it ?

Comment: Android 6.0.1
I am using a navigation drawer to navigate to other pages and go back to the page (the one I posted here) then the image view placed at the top instead of what it should behave as I programmed it.